# html parsing in c#

Tags: c#

How can i parse values from the scoreboard of http://www.cricinfo.com/nzvaus2010/engine/current/match/423789.html

---

But how it could be managed? i am stuck how to fetch data and store it in database

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you start reading, this looks like a good place to start

> [Screen Scraping Tutorial using C#
>   .NET](http://mhinze.com/archive/screen-scraping-tutorial-using-c-net/)

Answer (score 0):

It won't be easy, looking at the source of the page, it's all dynamic.  You're going to have to pull the javascript apart to figure out where it's getting it's data from and use that.  Conveniently, it's written in jquery.

Comment: And as a small aside: Go Aussies... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much data you are trying to get but there is an rss feed on the site http://www.cricinfo.com/rss/livescores.xml

Comment: feeds only give the updates of scores.
My requirements are to fetch to complete scoreboard and commentary to tae application.